# How to make different caption placement for figures on odd and even pages?

Tags: floats, positioning, double-sided

For small figures, I want for captions to go on the right or on the left depending on the page number, whether it is odd or even. To do that I define the command `\row` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\row}[2]{%
    \ifodd\value{page}
        #2 \hfil #1
    \else
        #1 \hfil #2
    \fi
}
```

Typically, it is used inside the `figure` environment, for example,

```
\begin{figure}
\row{%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.67\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2011-03-03}
  \end{minipage}%
}{%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
    \caption{The transition temperature vs. density of the hydrogen} 
    \label{fig:03-03}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
```

This works as desired in most cases, however, sometimes, placement of the caption goes wrong. I wonder why? And how to modify my code to avoid troubles?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about the circumstances under which "placement of the caption goes wrong." E.g., does it happen if there are multiple floats on a page? Does it only happen on verso (even-numbered) or on recto (odd-numbered) pages?

Comment: @Igor I wrote a solution for this at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45855/963

Comment: @Mico: unfortunetly I cannot at the moment specify condition when my code fails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `refcount` package:

```
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{figureposcount}
\newcommand{\row}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{figureposcount}\label{figurepos\thefigureposcount}%
  \ifodd\getpagerefnumber{figurepos\thefigureposcount}
    #2 \hfil #1%
  \else
    #1 \hfil #2%
  \fi
}
```

However you could also consider the `sidecap` package that does what you want without a special syntax (apart using `SCfigure` instead of `figure`).

Comment: Every answers given above are good. I have accepted this one because `refcount` package was already installed on my computer :) and because actually I expected something like this: set a label, convert `\pageref` to a number an so on.

Answer (score 10):

Due to the asynchronous nature of the output routine, the `page` counter isn't reliable. Use, e.g., the `scrextend` package and its `\ifthispageodd` macro instead.