# Make left-hand pages' `\marginpar` text right-aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, conditionals, marginpar, sv-classes

`\marginpar`s only appear on the right margins of right-hand pages of my manuscript. For left-hand pages, they are are so far to the left that they aren't even on the page.

The reason is because the text of `\marginpars` are left-aligned.

How do I make the `\marginpar`s of left-hand pages right-aligned so they are next to the body text?

```
\documentclass{svmono}

\usepackage[paperwidth=15.5cm, paperheight=23.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in \marginpar{[245]} reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Another page:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. \marginpar{[246]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide us some code which shows your problem. If you want to force the margins to look like you explicitly want you should have a look on the `geometry` package. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry

Comment: I don't know svmono but most classes have a `oneside` option that gives odd and even pages the same layout

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want right- and left-hand pages.

Comment: Oh OK you want twoside but with even margins the geometry package is what you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Specifically what option for `geometry`, though?

Comment: In the class's source code (available [here](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0)), the `svmono` class sets the odd and even margins to the same width: `\setlength\oddsidemargin{63\p@}\setlength\evensidemargin{63\p@}`. The output of `\marginpar` should be printed as expected, irrespective of the page number's parity. Something else in your preamble must change something, but people will be able to tell you what only if you edit your question and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @Jubobs: Thanks. I tried that, but it did some strange things because it duplicates the text. I need a command like it, but that would detect whether it's in the left or right page's margin. For example: `\marginpar{#1\hfill}` if it's in the the right margin of a right-hand page or `\marginpar{\hfill #1}` if it's in the left margin of a left-hand page. Is there a way to detect whether one is in the left- or right-hand page?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jubobs: Done, but I'm not sure it really helps at all. The crux of my question is how to detect and change a command's behavior depending if I'm on a left- or right-hand page.

Comment: Here's the answer: `\newcommand{\mymarginpar}[1]{\ifodd\thepage\marginpar{#1}\else\marginpar{\hfill #1}\fi}`

Comment: @Geremia: `\ifodd` expects an integer number, but `\thepage` could be a roman number. Also it is not guaranteed that the page number of `\thepage` is correct. Because of the asynchronous output routine of LaTeX, the decision about page breaks is done later. Therefore references should be used to get the correct page number in the next LaTeX run.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Yes, I noticed that: if a paragraph bleeds from an even to an odd page, it thinks it's an odd page even though it's really even… How do I use references to get the correct page #? thanks

Comment: @Geremia: For example, see [How to make different caption placement for figures on odd and even pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53566/16967).

Comment: Ah, I was trying to pass `\pageref{}` to `\ifodd`, but I needed to use `\getpagerefnumber{}`. So: `\newcommand{\mymarginpar}[1]{\label{marginpar:#1}\ifodd\getpagerefnumber{marginpar:#1}\marginpar{#1}\else\marginpar{\hfill #1}\fi}` does the trick beautifully! thanks! ☺