# Prohibiting figures from the left column

Tags: floats, two-column

Is it possible to have a twocolumn document with text and figures, where text can appear in either column, but figures must be in the right column? [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45849/text-on-the-left-figure-on-the-right) is superficially what I need, but it seems more of a wrapping issue than a float issue.

I am trying to mimic my firm's style guide, which requires two column documents with figures on the right.

I am using the report class with the `twocolumn` option, but other similar classes would do the job too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this just forces text page floats to the right, `\clearpage` still flushes all floats to the first available column.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\def\f{\begin{figure}\rule{1cm}{1cm}\caption{fff}\end{figure}}
\def\t{one two three four five six sevn eight nine ten eleven}
\def\tt{Red green \t. Blue yellow orange purple \t, \t, \t, \t.\par}

\makeatletter

\g@addto@macro\@floatplacement{%
\if@firstcolumn
\global\@colnum\z@
\fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\t\f\t\f\tt\f\t\f\tt\f\tt\f\tt\tt\f\f\f\t\f\t\f\tt\tt\tt
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the best way to prohibit `[p]` floats from the first column as well? I tried `\global\@fpmin\textheight` as well as your solution. It seems to work, but is there a better way, or are there any risks?

Comment: @Hugh not global for p column settings (see `\@floatplacement` in latex.ltx)

Comment: Is that what `:=G` vs `:=L` means? (Global vs Local)

Comment: @Hugh yes although I was looking at the code not the doc (there is a comment `% Floatpage bit, local:`  as well as lack of `\global` :-)

Comment: Haha ok! So do I just remove `\global` or is there a `\local` equivalent?

Comment: @Hugh that should be fine (no time to test now though)